# Getting null in response.getEntity() in ContainerResponse filter

Tags: java, jersey

Sometimes when I call to `response.getEntity()`, I'm getting `null`. But I don't understand the reason and I don't know how to ensure that the value that I'm getting in the `response.getEntity()` will always be not `null`.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
    durationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        requestBody = IOUtils.toString(request.getEntityInputStream(), Charsets.UTF_8);
        in = IOUtils.toInputStream(requestBody);
        request.setEntityInputStream(in);
    } catch(EOFException ex){
        log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (in != null)
                in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return request;
}

@Override
public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response) {
    ObjectMapper objMapper=null;
    String output = objMapper.writeValueAsString(response.getEntity());
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the entity stream in the request filter only set's the entity for incoming *request*. It has nothing to do with the response entity. The `getEntity()` in the response filter is the *response* entity, and it will only every have something if you actually return an entity from your *resource method*. That's where the response entity will come from.